# What is a Dwarven Key used for?

Tags: guild-wars-2

A Longhorn Ram I killed in **Dredgehaunt Cliffs** dropped a **Dwarven Key**. It says it's an event item, but it wasn't dropped during an event, so I'm left wondering what the purpose of this key is.

[image]

What is the **Dwarven Key** used for?

Comment: I ended up just trashing these as I left the zone for higher areas... now I'm curious too.

Comment: @MatthewScharley See my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key is used to open a door north of the Grey Road Waypoint in Dredgehaunt Cliffs, which starts the event **Kill the imp lord to stop him from summoning more imps**. The event is a battle against a Veteren Imp and small horde of Imps. After finishing the Event you'll be able to loot a chest, which will be located in the room behind the door.

**The door is located just north of the Grey Road Waypoint in Dredgehaunt Cliffs. I've marked it on this map with a star.**

[image]

**The door to the Event**

[image: The door leading to the tomb]

**Surprise! A whole bunch of lovely Imps to maul your face off.**

[image]

**Once you take down the hoard of Imps, the Imp Lord is fairly easy to take down.**

[image]

**Success! Now reward yourself to a chest of goodies.**

[image]

Comment: There are more than just one tomb! See if you can find them all. I've found three so far :) One was the Imp, one had an 'Ancient Veteran Destroyer' and the other was sealed up and un-openable :)

Answer (score 0):

The key is bound to an old event that does not exists anymore:

> Used to open tomb and start an event North of Grey Road Waypoint in Dredgehaunt Cliffs.

See http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Dwarven_Key

Comment: +1 You have the general location right,but the event still exists. See my answer.